# format of date string for strtotime() function in php

Tags: php

I have a following string:

```
$time = "01/01/2015"; // format is m/d/Y
```

I want to convert it to an integer value using strtotime() function so that I can compare it with another date. This is the integer value that I get after I convert it to string:

```
strtotime($time); // Gives me => int(1420092000)
```

**My Question:**

Looking at the above format of time string, how will the strtotime() function know that the format of the string is "m/d/Y" or "d/m/y"? Do I have to specify the format in strtotime() function as a second parameter if that is possible?

Comment: If you want to disambiguate dates cleanly, start looking at [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said on the php.net manual for strtotime:

Note:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>   To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So, if you use slashes to seperate, it will assume month / day / year, and if you use dash or a dot, php will assume day - month - year.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to specify the format for `strtotime()`, you specify it with using `/`, `.` or `-`.

As a quote from the manual:

> Note: Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

But if you want to see the implementation of this function you can search for it in the php github source code here: https://github.com/php/php-src

Here is the implementation of `strtotime()`: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.c#L1442